# What is the difference between "a half walnut cake" and "half a walnut cake"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> There was **half a** walnut cake with pink icing in the cupboard.
>   There was **a half** walnut cake with pink icing in the cupboard.

What is the difference between both of the above sentences?

Answer (score 3):

*Half a walnut cake* means "half of a [cake made with walnuts]"—that is, a walnut cake of which only half remains.

*A half walnut cake* is an unusual construction. If I encountered it I would take it to mean either "a cake made with half-walnuts" (which would presumably be a cake made with [walnuts divided in half]) or "a cake of which half was made with walnuts and the other half made with something else".

These meanings are of course so odd that, as @Catija suggests in the Comments, most readers would realize pretty quickly that what the writer meant by *a half walnut cake* was probably "half of a walnut cake", so it's a pretty minor error.

And of course it's entirely acceptable to speak of ***a*** half (of) a walnut cake.

Comment: Generally I agree (particularly that it's ambiguous), though I think in lazy English, they could be considered to be the same... for example, the simpler version "half a cake" vs "a half [of a] cake".

Comment: @Catija - adjusted.

Comment: @Catjia For native speakers there's really no such thing as lazy English, just informal English. Also, in "half a cake" I believe half may be a quantifier, but in "a half cake" it's definitely an adjective. For the former the implication is that only half a cake remains, while in the latter it's implied that the cake started at half. "Only a half of a cake was there." != "Only a half cake was there." Compare also "He was a half American" vs. "He was a half of an American" (which is very strange).

Comment: @eijen you're talking about two utterly different things. You can't compare a half cake to "a half American"... particularly considering that the average speaker would say "he was half American"... without the "a" at all.

Comment: I would understand *a half walnut cake* to refer to a retail option. The local supermarket sells full cakes and half cakes.  "When you're at the supermarket, pick up a half walnut cake for dessert".

Comment: @Catjia Try "It was a half green light" vs. "It was a half of a green light", then. I don't think my example was wrong, though, even if most people would go for adjective _American_ rather than noun _American_.

Comment: @eijen There are all sorts of reasons errors and ambiguities may creep into speech; but to **write** "a half walnut cake" argues slovenly thinking, or a lazy and discourteous indifference to one's readers.

Comment: @StoneyB True, in writing it's different. I thought Catjia was talking about spoken English, tho.